# Hide the facebook plugin initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have a simple .share-toggle toggle link. When you click it the facebook comment plugin should show. It should be hidden initally The problem was that if I hide it using the css, and I click the toggle, the FB comment plugin doesn't show. So I thought of hiding the FB plugin only after it has loaded with the code below... still no luck. It only works if I don't hide the plugin.

```
      var isLoaded = false;
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      channelUrl : '#', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    $('#fb-root').trigger('facebook:init');

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

    $("#fb-root").bind("facebook:init", function() {
        console.log('loaded');
        $('.social-sharing').hide();
    });

    $('.share-toggle').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.social-sharing').slideToggle('fast');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are hiding the right container.

If your facebook social tool is rendered to `.share-toggle` and you have set this element to `display:none` with your css, the facebook code might remove this css property after beeing loaded.

So what you should do is wrap your social element into a container.

```
<div class="social-container" style="display:none">
    <div class="social-sharing"></div>
</div>
```

This way you can easily toggle the container in order to show or hide your social widget.

```
$('.share-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('body').find('.social-container').slideToggle('fast');
});
```